# Retrieve number of bytes send over logical interface from CLI (Juniper router)

Tags: monitoring, command-line-interface, juniper

Is there any simple method to check from CLI how many bytes has been sent over physical/logical router interface? I am interested in Juniper devices.
It would be great if command result was a short output containing only (or almost only) information that I am interested in.

So far, I tried `show interface fe-0/0/0 statistics` but it gives very long output not containing information about bytes sent (only pps information). Command `show interfaces fe-0/0/0 detail` prints number of bytes sent, but it is places among others data and as I've written previously, I'd like to have it in a single line format (or almost-single-line format :))

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your purpose wouldnt be better served by using SNMP?  'simple' information is what it does best.

Comment: indeed. check http://goo.gl/24e0J for JunOS enterprise mib and http://goo.gl/Er7Dq for the juniper-if-mib.

Comment: I cannot use SNMP for this purpose, because I am testing some modified custom version of SNMP and I want to compare these two values

Comment: It sounds like you will have to get the bytes sent via the show detail, and then do a bunch of perl (or your choice) post processing to get the information down to exactly you want... at which point you will have re-implemented snmp in a less scalable fashion.